# Objective-C on iPhone - use of NSOperationQueue and NSInvocationOperation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, release, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a UITableViewController which I'm populating with data from a web service.  While the data is downloading I'm using NSInvocationOperation with NSOperationQueue to run the web service call on a background thread while displaying a progress indicator on the UI.  This all works fine, but I just want to ensure I'm handling the objects properly.  My code is as follows :

```
NSOperationQueue *backgroundTaskQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *webServiceOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(loadListDataOperation)
                                        object:nil];
[backgroundTaskQueue addOperation:webServiceOp];
[webServiceOp release];
```

My memory management knowledge tells me I should be releasing backgroundTaskQueue at some point but not sure where - should it just be in the dealloc() method of the UITableViewController?

Any help appreciated,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be releasing the queue if you allocated it. The `dealloc` method would be an ideal place for this.